# How to show A success message on jsf 2

Tags: jsf-2

How can i make the success message display out? I have the following code, but only the warning message appear. What do i have to change so that the success message  will be display out in my success page ?

**userbean.java** :

```
  public String Login() throws Exception {
     String status = "failure"; 
    current=userBo.validateUser(getLogin(),getPass()); 
    if(current!=null){ exist=false; status = "success"; 
    String message = "submitted successfully !!"; 
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(message)); }
     exist=true; return status; }
```

---

**login.xhtml :**

```
<f:view>
                    <h:form>
                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                            <tr>
                                <th>Username</th>
                                <td><h:inputText value="#{user.login}"
                                        styleClass="login-inp" /></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Password</th>
                                <td><h:inputSecret value="#{user.pass}"
                                        onfocus="this.value=''" styleClass="login-inp" /></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th></th>
                                <!-- <td><input type="button" class="submit-login"  /> -->
                                <td><h:commandButton action="#{user.checkUser}"  styleClass="submit-login" />
                                <h:messages  globalOnly="true"  />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </h:form>
                </f:view>
```

---

**success.xhtml :**

```
 <h:form>
    <h:body>

        <h1>heyyyy ,y sucseded  !!!</h1> <br/><br/>

        <h:commandLink  action ="#{user.logout}" > disconnect </h:commandLink>

    </h:body>
    </h:form>
```

**warning message :**

```
Infos: WARNING: FacesMessage(s) have been enqueued, but may not have been displayed.
sourceId=null[severity=(INFO 0), summary=(submitted successfully !!), detail=(submitted successfully !!)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `<h:messages globalOnly="true" />` is been placed in the wrong view. You placed it in `login.xhtml`, but you're navigating to `success.xhtml` on success instead of returning to `login.xhtml`. If you put the `<h:messages globalOnly="true" />` in `success.xhtml`, then it will be displayed the way you expected.

Answer (score 0):

on your action method i.e. action="#{user.checkUser}" return a string that string will decide which page to show using your faces-config.xml file.

eg.
        < navigation-rule>

```
        < from-view-id>*< /from-view-id>                
            < navigation-case>
               <from-outcome>ReturnedString</from-outcome>
               <to-view-id>success.xhtml(path of your file)</to-view-id>
            <redirect/>
        </navigation-case>
    < /navigation-rule>
```

this will definately work.

Comment: You're not understanding the concrete problem. Besides, OP is using JSF 2.0 which supports the new implicit navigation feature without the need for clumsy XML navigation rules.